# Laravel 5:Pass Multiple Array From Controller to View

Tags: laravel-5

I just started shifting to Laravel 5 from Symfony and I am wondering how to pass multiple arrays from my controller to my view.

I am trying to use PHP's compact() function but I am unable to properly get them in the view.

```
$users = Users::all();
$projects = Projects::all();
$foods = Foods::all();

return ('controller.view', compact('users','projects','foods'));
```

What is the best for me to be able to transfer all these array of objects to my view.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're missing call to the view method in your example

```
return view('controller.view', compact('users','projects','foods'));
```

That said, the rest of the syntax is correct.

In your view you can access those variables as you would normally. If you're using blade for example.

In `resources/views/controller/view.blade.php`

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    {{$user->property}}
@endforeach
```

If you're not using blade.

In `resources/views/controller/view.php`

```
<?php
foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo $user->property;
}
?>
```

Comment: Sorry I had a typo when I was making the original post. My code had return view() in it but for some reason the compact was failing.

Answer (score 7):

I found the answer to my question.

```
return view('controller.view', array('users' => $users,
               'projects' => $projects ,'foods' => $foods)
```

And in blade I just normally accessed them through the foreach iteration.

Comment: Hey Ben thanks for the very fast and insightful reply. Unfortunately for some reason, the compact() function was failing on the view. I was also for sure that it should be able to handle it. Passing the variables through an array worked for me.